# Grails - body onload being called after script method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails

Not really sure what is causing this, or if it's related to Grails at all.

I have a method that I want to call on body load that goes first. Then a method in a script tag that goes second. I always assumed the body onload method call would go first - I guess I was wrong.

The order of alerts is 3, then 1, then 2.

Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>${cname} Organization Chart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'custom.css')}" type="text/css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery.jOrgChart.css')}" type="text/css"/>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap.min.css')}" type="text/css"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'prettify.css')}" type="text/css"/>   

    <g:javascript src="prettify.js" />
    <g:javascript src="jquery.jOrgChart.js" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        alert('3');
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $("#org").jOrgChart({
                chartElement : '#chart',
                dragAndDrop  : true
            });
        });
    </script>

<body onload="alert('1');prettyPrint();alert('2');">

    <ul id='org' style='display:none'></ul>

    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<body onload=...>` actually *(and oddly)* sets the `window.onload` event, which is invoked after all the initially requested external resources *(images, scripts, etc.)* are done loading.

You probably should use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` handler or inline the script, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to put all of your javascript in a javascript file and not execute any from the HTML.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>${cname} Organization Chart</title>
        ... snip ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="someJSFile.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='org' style='display:none'></ul>
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

someJSFile.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    prettyPrint();

    $("#org").jOrgChart({
        chartElement: '#chart',
        dragAndDrop: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**onload** event is fired immediately after a page has been loaded.This is fired when the web page has completely loaded all content.

The one inside the script tag is fired as soon as the parser encounters it.

So the sequence in which the alerts fired is perfectly normal.